# Shortcut Recorder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, shortcut, hotkeys

i wanted to implement the shortcut recorder but i cant get this working, because their wiki isnt really helpful.

I asked me whether some of you would know a full-featured tutorial or someone could write here a tutorial on how to implement the shortcut recorder on a mac application.

What i did so far is i installed the shortcut recorder plugin added the gui elements to my .xib and i imported all the classes from Shortcut recorder into my project. What are the next steps i need to do ?

Thanks

Comment: Not useful tags. Consider picking better ones so that people will notice your question.

Comment: What programming language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: Looks like he is talking about the Cocoa framework Shortcut Recorder, the details on http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/wiki/GettingStartedInSVNTrunk should suffice

Answer (score 0):

The .xib tutorial works for xcode3 only.

So do it with code. It is the easist way currently.

For xcode4, there is my patch to use 'user defined runtime attribute' [here](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/issues/detail?id=58). To follow this, you need to understand more than basic about interface builder.